# Como validar un usuario y si este se equivoca limpiar el campo? en c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Soy nuevo en c# (Windows Form)la verdad se me hace un lenguaje muy bueno

Estoy creando un login, ya logre hacer la conexión y que valide si es o no el usuario, pero ahora quisiera, si el usuario ingresa mal su contraseña lo regrese y limpie el valor del campo, y distinguir si el usuario es normal o admin..

logre hacer este avance pero hasta aquí llegue

```
 public void logins()
        {
            try
            {
                string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["produccion"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cnn))
                {
                    conexion.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Login,Password FROM usuarios " +
                        "WHERE Login=@user AND Password=@passwd", conexion)) 
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", textBox1.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passwd", textBox2.Text);

                        if (textBox1.Text.Trim() == "")
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Por Favor Ingrese un usuario");
                            this.textBox1.Focus();
                            return;
                        }   

                        if (textBox2.Text.Trim() == "")
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Por Favor Ingrese una contraseña");
                            this.textBox2.Focus();
                            return;
                        }

                        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        if (dr.Read())
                        { 
                            this.Hide();
                            new Factura().Show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Datos incorrectos.", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
```

esa es la función que mando llamar desde el botón.

listo agregue el código para que lo limpie.

```
this.textBox2.Focus();
this.textBox2.Clear();
```

Comment: deberias de agregar un campo mas a tu tabla que sea el que distinga entre admin y usuario, por ejemplo campo llamado [TIPO] que sea tipo de dato bit(true,false) y ya con ese campo puedes identificarlos, true para el admin y flase para los usuarios.

Comment: ok usas c# pero tu aplicacion es windows forms o web

Comment: @MiguelZarate Listo, es Windows Form

Answer (score 1):

Solo necesitas agregar el método Clear a tus textbox después de tu validación:

```
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            this.Hide();
            new Factura().Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Datos incorrectos.", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK.ToString());
            textbox1.Clear();
            textbox2.Clear();
        }
```

Para tu tema de diferenciar entre usuarios y administradores agrega un campo a tu tabla **usuarios** y devuelva en tu consulta:

```
SELECT Login, Password, PerfilUsuario FROM usuarios WHERE Login = @User AND Password = @passwd
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo habia agregado, pero al parecer me dicen que tengo que hacerlo con un sp de sql server....